# HttpContext works differently in visual studio Code with OmniSharp extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-mvc

I installed Visual Studio Code and install C# Extension

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp

When I open existing **Asp.Net Core 2** project I can edit files and run web server with debug option (`Debug > Start Debugging`)

But then I got null exception about HttpContext (debug from visual studio 2017 do not throw this error)

```
@User.Identity.Name.Replace(@"Domain\", string.Empty)
```

When I change code to

```
@System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();
```

It works. So it seems to me that C# Extension run different web server or with different settings than Visual Studio 2017. I have assumption that issue can be in **Windows Authentication setting**, but i dont have clue where to setup this ?

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related with hosting `Asp.Net Core`. In general, there are three options for launching new project, `IIS`, `IIS Express` and `Project`. When launching from `VS 2017`, you may use `IIS Express` which supports `Windows Authentcation` and you could configure it by `launchsettings.json`.

But, launching from `IIS` or `IIS Express` is not supported in `VS Code`. Then you will lauch `.NET Core` by `Project` when using `VS Code`. When you use self-hosted by `Project`, you will need to use `Http.sys` with `Windows Authencation` to support `Windows Authentication`.

For resolving your issue, you could modify `Program.cs` like below to use `Http.sys` with `Windows Authentcation`.

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseHttpSys(options => {
                    options.Authentication.Schemes =
                        AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM | AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate;
                        options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = false;
                })
                .Build();
```